# How to build pyodide?

Tags: cmake, building, pyodide, emsdk

During the build of pyodide using the [using make](https://pyodide.org/en/stable/development/building-from-sources.html#using-make) method described in the documentation. I am coming across the following error during the emsdk step. Please direct me towards a solution for building the core packages in pyodide `PYODIDE_PACKAGES='core'`

Error:

```
Unpacking '/media/savakarrohan/Projects/pyodide/emsdk/emsdk/zips/node-v14.18.2-linux-x64.tar.xz' to '/media/savakarrohan/Projects/pyodide/emsdk/emsdk/node/14.18.2_64bit'
Done installing tool 'node-14.18.2-64bit'.
Installing tool 'releases-upstream-49d45744895c7d7e28acd94a385d7ee361653b4a-64bit'..
Error: Downloading URL 'https://storage.googleapis.com/webassembly/emscripten-releases-builds/linux/49d45744895c7d7e28acd94a385d7ee361653b4a/wasm-binaries.tbz2': <urlopen error [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution>
error: installation failed!
make[1]: *** [Makefile:9: emsdk/.complete] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/media/savakarrohan/Projects/pyodide/emsdk'
make: *** [Makefile:188: emsdk/emsdk/.complete] Error 2
```

Comment: The path `https://storage.googleapis.com/webassembly/emscripten-releases-builds/linux/49d45744895c7d7e28acd94a385d7ee361653b4a/wasm-binaries.tbz2` is correct. Looks like the problem is on your side.

Comment: I recommend using the Pyodide Docker container to build Pyodide. That will not solve your current problem but will make sure you are using the same versions of the tools which will solve many future problems. https://pyodide.org/en/stable/development/building-from-sources.html